# Mocking AngularJS Webservice using Jasmine Unit Test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I want to mock my Angular JS method using Jamine. My code is:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var app = angular.module('mymodulee', []);
   app.controller('mycontroller', function ($scope, $http, $log) {
    $scope.ButtonClick = function (Id) {

        var response = $http({
            method: "get",
            url: http://localhost:8080/Access/Tasks.DefectManagement/Services/Services.asmx/GetEligibilityDetails",
            params: {
                CovId: Id
            }

        });
        return response;
    }
});
```

And my Jasmine Test Case is:-

```
    it('EligibilityDetails', function () {

    var myserv, httpBackend;

    inject(function ($httpBackend, _myserv_) {
        myserv = _myserv_;
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    });



afterEach(function () {
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
    var $scope = {};
    var controller = $controller('PatientDefectManagementCtrl', { $scope: $scope });

    var returnData = {};
    httpBackend.expectGET("http://localhost:8080/Access/Tasks.DefectManagement/Services/Services.asmx/GetEligibilityDetails").respond(returnData);

    var returnedPromise = myserv.get(3904142);

    var result;
    returnedPromise.then(function (response) {
        result = response.data;
    });

    httpBackend.flush();

    expect(result).toEqual(returnData);



});
```

But its is giving an error. Can anyone please tell what changes I should make in my code so that i can run the test case using Jasmine Unit test.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 describe('test',function(){
 afterEach(function () {
httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();});
 var myserv, httpBackend;
beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_,_myserv__){
myserv = _myserv_;
httpBackend = $httpBackend;});
it('EligibilityDetails', function () {
var $scope = {};
var controller = $controller('PatientDefectManagementCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
var returnData = {};
httpBackend.expectGET("http://localhost:8080/Access/Tasks.DefectManagement/Services/Services.asmx/GetEligibilityDetails").respond(returnData);

var returnedPromise = myserv.get(3904142);

var result;
returnedPromise.then(function (response) {
    result = response.data;
});

httpBackend.flush();

expect(result).toEqual(returnData);});});
```

Comment: Can you help me with the code, what change I need to make.

Comment: Specify the returneddata value as something like you are expecting to get in result both should be same. If you can tell me error i can help you more.

Comment: My error is: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/$injector/unpr?p0=myservProvider%20%3C-%20myserv

Comment: make sure myserv service exist and it has been added in the configuration file

Comment: Yes, the service does exist and added to configuration file  <script src="/PatientManagement/Angular/Service.js">

Comment: then use beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_,_myserv_){

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117896/discussion-between-rahul-aggarwal-and-vikash).

Comment: giving error: Cannot read property 'verifyNoOutstandingExpectation' of undefined